# How to connect to Docker API from Docker container using Python?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Good day!

I have difficulties on connecting to docker engine api using Python with official library docker from docker container.

Always works fine in my machine, but when I build image and started with docker-compose handled error, that python can't connect to docker host.

What I tried to do?

1. Launch to container and run command

   `import docker`
   `client = docker.DockerClient(base_url="tcp://127.0.0.1:2375")`
   `client = docker.from_env()`

Get

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f91bd81d6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Please, hint me how to configure container, so I can connect to local docker engine using python docker library.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount docker.sock to containers docker.sock

volumes:

- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock